# Inserting multiple values in Mysql using Nodejs and notifying user with a response

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am making a new webservice where i send a curl command with JSON and the JSON contains a array as

```
[{tempid:1,email:abc@123,address:asd},{tempid:2,email:abc@12345,address:asd45},{tempid:3,email:abc@1234,address:asd4}]
```

Now when i pass and insert the array in a mysql table tempid is just to show a mapping to the user to the contact id generated in the database as tempid:1 is now inserted and in database it has cid 120 , like this for tempid2 and 3 ,

But when i am trying to show the client the updated values it shows only one value , last last change not the whole updated Array. Its becuase of the async nature of the connection.querry function , so i need help in this , here is my webservice

**contactadd webservice -->**

```
for(var i=0;i<=request.body.contact.length-1;i++)
            {
             if(request.body.contact[i].tempid)
                { var ardata=new Array();
                    var o=request.body.contact[i];
                    pair=Object.keys(o).map(function(a){ return [a, o[a]] });
                    AM.addcontact(pair,request.session.user,request.body.contact.length,function(e,o){
                        if(!o)
                        {
                             response.send('something went wrong'+e);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                           //response.send(o);
                        }

                    });


                }
    }
```

**Here is the update function in the database.js script -->**

```
//ContactSync-addcontact module for database 
exports.addcontact=function (arr,email,addnum,callback)
{ 
  var counter=0;
  var uid;
  var data=new Array();
  var showinsert=new Array();
  var values=new Array();
  var datatable=new Array();
  var inserting=new Array();

  var tempid=0;
   connection.query('SELECT UID FROM user where email1="'+email.email+'"',function(err,rows,fields){
    if(err)
    {
     throw err;
    }
    else
    {
    if(rows[0]!=undefined)
    {
     uid=rows[0]['UID'];
    }
    else
    {
    uid="no id in database";
    }
    }
    });// get the UID of the inserting user

    // make array of user provided data
    for(var j=0;j<=arr.length-1;j++)
    {
     if(arr[j][0]!='tempid')
     {
      data.push(arr[j][0]);
     }
     else
     {
      tempid=arr[j][1];
     }
    }

    connection.query('SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns where table_schema="webservice" AND table_name="usercontacts"',function(err,rows,fields){
    if(err)
    {
     throw err;
    }
    else
    {

    for(var i=0;i<=rows.length-1;i++)
    {
      datatable.push(rows[i]['column_name']);

    }
    }
       for(var k=0;k<=datatable.length-1;k++)
        {
          if(inArray(data[k],datatable))
          {
            inserting.push(data[k]);
          }
        }
        if(inserting.length>0)
        {


            for(var z=0;z<=arr.length-1;z++)
            {
              if(inArray(arr[z][0],inserting))
               { 

                 values.push('"'+arr[z][1]+'"');

               }
            }


            // Insert tempid values and data in the usercontacts table with inserting and values

            connection.query('INSERT INTO usercontacts (cid,uid,'+inserting+') VALUES("","'+uid+'",'+values+')',function(err,rows,fields){
            if(err)
            {
            throw err;
            }
            else
            {  
                connection.query('SELECT * FROM usercontacts WHERE uid="'+uid+'" ORDER BY cid DESC LIMIT 0,'+addnum+'',function(err,rows,fields){
                if(err)
                {
                    throw err;
                }
                else

                {   showinsert.push('temp-id: '+tempid+',cid:'+rows[0].cid+',uid:'+uid);
                    //for(var i=0;i<=inserting.length-1;i++)
                    forEach(inserting,function(row,index)
                    {
                      showinsert.push(inserting[index]+":"+values[index]);
                      counter+=1;
                    });

                    callback(null,showinsert);

                }

                });
            }

            });

            //insertion finished 


        }
        else
        {
          callback("Please Provide atleast one field to enter with tempid");
        }

  });


}
```

I just need to insert all the callback in a array which has been inserted and show user that array ,please help , completely stuck and then only i am trying StackOverflow.

Thank you for reading till the end BTW

Comment: Three points of contention... First, would suggest wrapping your check/insert into a single SQL statement, that returns the existing, or new uid for a given user matching against an email address... Second, would suggest parameterized queries, not string concatenation...  Third, look into `npm install async --save` the async module will provide methods for iterating against your collection, and returning a completed result set or error.  Fourth, you should use a transaction for your entire process so that it can success or fail as a whole.

Comment: hi thanks for your comment , http://pastebin.com/V35UZdPw i have pasted my new updated code on the service side , i am running a foreach but the variable ardata remain empty/nothing on response , please help

Comment: assuming ardata is an array `[]` try ardata.push(value)

Comment: ardata is a simlple variable i have tried that , infact i have just used Async.series

Comment: Here is the current code -->
http://pastebin.com/jxyaprTz

Comment: The array ardata , runs twice as you can see in the output in the end , and it did not fill anything with ardata.push(o); ? strange ? please help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the specific problem is, but there are some problems with the code you've shared that will bite you sooner or later. One of these may be causing your problem.

**Race conditions**

If the query `SELECT UID FROM user where email1=` for any reason takes longer than the `SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns` just below it then you won't have a value for the variable `uuid` and your logic will fail. Remember that these calls are non-blocking, so you can't rely on one finishing before the other one unless they're nested or use another flow-control mechanism (As @Tracker points out, [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) is popular).

**Catching edge cases**

In the line below you're assigning a string value to the `uid` variable and then continuing to use that variable even though it now contains an error message.

```
    uid="no id in database";
```

Doing that means that your code later on will have trouble reacting. Instead use a different variable, leave the `uid = undefined` or immediately return the callback with an error, e.g.

```
    return callback(new Error("user not found"));
```

**Reporting errors**

Don't throw errors in Node unless you want to kill the process, e.g. dependency problems during server startup. It doesn't work like Java, async errors are not caught by try/catch and will kill your process or leave you in a state that's hard to reason about. Instead make the error object your first parameter to the callback and return it immediately, like this:

```
    if ( err ) return callback(err);
```

Then in your client code you can always check the first parameter to see if there was a problem.

**Security problem**

As @Tracker mentioned, **don't ever do the this**:

```
    connection.query('SELECT UID FROM user where email1="'+email.email+'"', ...
```

If the value of the variable is passed through as `"; drop table user;` or similar then you're in trouble. Instead you can use node-mysql's build in escaping like this:

```
    connection.query('SELECT UID FROM user where email1=?', [email.email], ...
```

**Whitelist**

You're querying `information_schema.columns` in order to detect which fields are valid then inserting them into `usercontacts`. This is a clever trick, but increases a 3 query process to 4 queries, and raises questions if there are any fields that a user shouldn't be inserting data into. Using a column whitelist may seem like more code to maintain, but would actually be simpler than all the code required to match columns dynamically.

**Arrays**

I don't see the source for the function `inArray()` but it looks like it does the same as `Array.prototype.indexOf()` so it may be better to use that. e.g.

```
    if ( datatable.indexOf(data[k]) > -1 ) inserting.push(data[k]);
```

Every line of custom code you can delete is a line of code you don't have to maintain.

Comment: thanks a lot for your valuable time and good lesson , i will always remember this from now. Thanks again.

Comment: I am making it from scratch again , this time i am using nesting of queries , is that a bad practice ?

Comment: Nesting is fine, but can become hard to follow if you go too deep. My suggestion would be to use nesting to begin with until you're comfortable with this style of code, then look into `async`. I'm not a fan of promises personally but that's an option too. Another tip, if you give your anonymous functions a name, e.g. `doSomething(function myUniquelyNamedCallback(){ ... })`, then the name will show up in your stack traces instead of 'anonymous function'.

Comment: *Another* tip... use node-inspector to add breakpoints to important points and you'll be able to walk through your app step by step, looking at the values of variables as you go